# JS Destructing the array and retrieve the values with spaces from API call

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I'm working on destructing the object, but I'm very confused.
The image above is the data I'm getting from the API(stockData), and I want to output the Symbol, and the values under Time Series. (open, high etc)

```
const displayStock = (stockData) => {
        console.log(stockData);

        //Output coding here...
        });


let currentStock = `${BASE_END_POINT}symbol=${ticker}&interval=5min&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
    fetch(currentStock).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    }).then((currentStockObject) => {
        displayStock(currentStockObject);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Errors are such ${error}`);
    });
```

If I were to get the values, how should I do it ?
I've tried foreach loop with various ways to target the object..

```
        stockData[0].forEach(item => {
            console.log(item);
            let {"2. Symbol":symbol} = item;
            console.log(`Ticker: ${symbol}`);            
        });
```

But it would only output the error which saying cannot read property foreach of undefined.
It's still hard for me to do the basic thing, but it even has spaces on their name, so it makes me harder to figure out :(

https://jsfiddle.net/apc4dn2g/

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please put a jsfiddle or some sort of snippet, would be much easier to help...

Comment: @V.Sambor Thanks, I added the link

Comment: Thanks, but I found the api already and manage answer, could you please check if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using [alphavantage](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) stock api.

The answer seems to be an object and the `TimeSeries` is a key which has appended an interval type at the end. (The interval you can pass it as a parameter when you do the api call)

Here is an example how I retrieve `high` and `low` value

```js
async function getStockJSON() {
try{
  const response = await fetch('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo');
  const jsonData = await response.json();
 
  const timeSeries = jsonData['Time Series (Daily)'];
  
  for(const key of Object.keys(timeSeries)) {
    const currTimeItem = timeSeries[key];
    
    let high;
    let low;
    
    for (const key of Object.keys(currTimeItem)) {
      if (key.includes('high')) {
        high = currTimeItem[key];
      }
      
      if (key.includes('low')) {
        low = currTimeItem[key];
      }
      
      if (high && low) {
        break;
      }
    }
    
    console.log('high: ', high);
    console.log('low: ', low);
  }
  
  
  } catch(error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
}

getStockJSON();
```

Because of the `keys` being so strangely given, I was forced to loop again over the inner object to identify if the key is `low` or `high`. It's not that highly performant, but it is a way of retrieving what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. it finally works after hours of struggling. Really much appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

```
var data=stockData[0]["Meta Data"]
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    if(key=="2. Symbol"){
        console.log(data[key]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you !! I combined two answers, and it finally works. Much appreciated !!